# Data-binding ng-model with object but display a value in field

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-ng-model

I am new to AngularJS and I am trying to wrap my head around a certain concept. I have figured out how to successfully perform one way data binding but still can't think of the best way of performing a two way bind with a complex object.

HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Project Lead" ng-model="currentproject.projectLeader.name" />
```

JS

```
$scope.ViewProject = function (project) {
    $http.get('api/projects/' + project.id)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.currentproject = data;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load selected project data: ' + error.message;
        });
    };
```

To simplify things, `projectLeader` has `projectLeader.id` and `projectLeader.name`.

I am trying to bind the full `projectLeader` object to the `input` field but I want the value of the `input` to display only the project `name`. Does this make sense? How would I go about retrieving the new `projectLeader` when the field changes? Is it best to do an `ng-change` on that field that calls another request to the server with the name inputted to retrieve the `id` for that person? Then modify the scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont bind the entire object to the input field. Bind only the name to the input text. Don't use ng-change, ng-change will be fired every time sompone changes the input field, so whenever the user presses a key ng-change will fire the method to save the data. Instead put a button to submit, or you can do it on enter press. I will try to put up a fiddle for you.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I am trying to allow them to modify the `currentproject`. So on the submit of that update, I should just return all of the project updates and resolve the `projectLeader.id` from the new `projectLeader.name`? How can i easily detect if this value was changed or not without having to do a comparison everytime an update occurs?

Comment: What are the values that you are expecting will change? If you are only binding the project leader's name then no property except the name will change so you can just compare that. Or if you want you can use forms and check if any field in the form in dirty.

Comment: I have a bunch of fields on a form that consist of properties from the `currentproject` object. The `projectLeader` piece happens to have an `id` and `name` tied to it. When a user updates the form, I am sending the whole form (`currentproject`) back to the server. So, what I should be doing is just check every time the form goes back to the server if the `projectLeader.name` field is dirty?

Comment: Well if you have a bunch of fields then you should definitely use a form. And check if the entire form is dirty

Comment: Thanks for all your help!